# Return equality from Mathematica function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, equality

I have a function that returns equalities, which I want to print,
for example, x==y, or 2x+5==10.
These usually have no meaning for mathematica, it cannot simplify it furhter.

However, sometimes the both sides are equal, but I want to be able to print the equality in unevaluated form: that is, I want Mathematica to print x==x, and not True.

A very simple example:

```
Print[printableEqual[x,y]]
```

should print x==y, while

```
Print[printableEqual[x,x]]
```

should print x==x

Edit:
The reason is that I have a relation among graphs. I would like to return things like

```
G1 == t*G2 + s*G3
```

where t,s are integers, and Gi are Graphics objects in Mathematica.
Just returning this works great, (Since Mathematica cannot simplify such things) EXCEPT G1 == G1 which will be True.

The trouble is that using Defer, or HoldForm gives

```
Private`lhs$714 == Private`rhs$714
```

as output, that is, the private variables in my package is not evaluated as my Graphics.

Comment: How about `printableEqual[x_,y_]:=Row[{x," \\[LongEqual] ",y}]`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Defer.html) to do this:

```
In[5]:= printableEqual[x_, y_] := Defer[x == y];
In[6]:= printableEqual[1, 2]
Out[6]= 1 == 2
```

Comment: Does not work if printableEqual is in a package, see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Another trick is to just use [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unevaluated.html):

```
In[1] := Print[Unevaluated[1 == 1]]
1==1
```

Comment: @Michael Could you clarify the difference of using Defer vs. Unevaluated here?

Comment: `Unevaluated` doesn't wrap anything around the expression. `Defer[expr]` is a wrapper that, when printed or output, displays as the unevaluated form of `expr`, but when used as input again, acts like the evaluated form of `expr`. `Unevaluated` just prevents evaluation "once", if you will. Put another way, `Head[Unevaluated[1==1]]` is `Equals`, but `Head[Defer[1==1]]` is `Defer`.

Comment: Actually, I think that `Unevaluated` does wrap the expression - it's just that the wrapping is transparent to most functions. Compare `{FullForm[Defer[1 + 1]],FullForm[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]}` and `{Head[Defer[1 + 1]], Head[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]}`. Also, see @Leonid's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856177/preventing-evaluation-of-mathematica-expressions/4856721#4856721).

Comment: `Unevaluated` does wrap, but is stripped, so its invisibility is a consequence of the evaluation process. If you wrap in several layers of Unevaluated, the inner ones will remain, for example `Head[Unevaluated[Unevaluated[Print["*"]]]]`. The problem with `Unevaluated` is that you never know how many times you need to nest it, and how many of them will be stripped - this depends on a particular evaluation, can also be data-dependent, so this is not a robust way of preventing the evaluation of expression except when we do it once, and need it once.

Comment: @Simon: your example `FullForm[Unevaluated[1 + 1]]` is a very special case. What happens really is that this `Unevaluated` *does* get stripped during the evaluation process. But, since there are no surrounding functions (and `FullForm` is really not a surrounding function in the way it works), the result is `Plus[1,1]` (not evaluated). In such cases (when no applicable rules were found for the parts where `Unevaluated` was stripped), `Unevaluated` is restored, which is what you observed. A very similar example was given by David Wagner in his book - this is where I learned about this.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I should have said that `Unevaluated` does not result in a *persistent* wrapper around the expression.

Comment: @Michael: your formulation of "persistent wrapper" is probably the best concise way to put it that I've seen - a good image to keep in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Usually one uses `HoldForm` for this sort of thing. `HoldForm` is a head that works like `Hold`, in that it doesn't evaluate its contents, but it's not displayed when it's printed as output, like so:

```
In[1]:= HoldForm[x == 3]
Out[1]= x == 3

In[2]:= HoldForm[x == x]
Out[2]= x == x
```

As with `Hold`, you can interpolate things into a `HoldForm` using `With` or function argument substitution, like so:

```
In[3]:= PrintableEqual[x_, y_] := HoldForm[x == y]

In[4]:= PrintableEqual[x, x]
Out[4]= x == x
```

However, this will mean that the arguments are evaluated before substitution, like so:

```
In[5]:= PrintableEqual[x + x, 2 x]
Out[5]= 2 x == 2x
```

If you don't want this to happen, you can use `SetAttributes` and `HoldAll`:

```
In[6]:= SetAttributes[PrintableEqual, {HoldAll}]

In[7]:= PrintableEqual[x + x, 2 x]
Out[7]= x + x == 2 x
```

Note that `HoldForm` is always there, it's just not displayed in output form:

```
In[8]:= PrintableEqual[x, x] // InputForm
Out[8]= HoldForm[x == x]
```

If you want to evaluate things, use `ReleaseHold`:

```
In[9]:= ReleaseHold@PrintableEqual[x, x]
Out[9]= True
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is to is use `Grid[]` to align all of your equalities - the added advantage is that since you don't actually create expressions with `Equal[]`, you don't have to prevent their evaluation.

```
In[1]:= Grid[Table[{LHS[i],"\[LongEqual]",RHS[i]},{i,2}],
             Alignment -> {Right,Center,Left}]
Out[1]= LHS[1] == RHS[1]
        LHS[2] == RHS[2]
```

On a similar vein, you could manually typeset using

```
printableEqual[LHS_, RHS_] := Row[{LHS, " \[LongEqual] ", RHS}]
```

or more generally

```
printableEqual[LHS_, mid___, RHS_] := Row[Riffle[{LHS, mid, RHS}, " \[LongEqual] "]]
```

---

By the way, the output from the `printableEqual[]` defined above can be converted back to a real Expression using `ToExpression[ToString[#]]&` or something like

```
toRealEqual[Row[lst_List]] := Equal@@lst[[1;;-1;;2]] /; OddQ[Length[lst]] && Union[lst[[2;;-2;;2]]] == {" \[LongEqual] "}
```