# Why does this expression substitution not work?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I want to use wolframalpha to find the probability of a line `y = a x + b` passes through the `point [2,8]`, when `a` and `b` are determined by fair dice roll.

This does what i want:

```
Count[Flatten[Table[a 2 + b, {a,6},{b,6}]],8]/
Length[Flatten[Table[a 2 + b, {a,6},{b,6}]]]
```

, but I don't like the repetition. I'm not fully certain why following will not work:

```
Count[x, 8]/Length[x] /. x -> Flatten[Table[a 2 + b, {a, 6}, {b, 6}]]
```

Can i get around this and what is happening?

Comment: Margus, if you have more *Mathematica* related questions I recommend you join us on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com -- it is far more active now than StackOverflow (for mathematica tag) and you will get better answers sooner.

Comment: Margus: PE level 12.  Well done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of evaluation in this is not what you desire:

```
Count[x, 8]/Length[x] /. x -> Flatten[Table[a 2 + b, {a, 6}, {b, 6}]]
```

The left side of `/.` evaluates before replacement, and therefore becomes: `Indeterminate`

You need to delay evaluation.  The normal method for this is to use a "pure function."  See [Function &](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) and [Slot #](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html):

```
Count[#, 8]/Length[#] & @ Flatten[Table[a 2 + b, {a, 6}, {b, 6}]]
```

It is possible to force ReplaceAll (short form `/.`) to work, but it is nonstandard:

```
Unevaluated[ Count[x, 8]/Length[x] ] /.
    x -> Flatten[Table[a 2 + b, {a, 6}, {b, 6}]]
```

`Unevaluted` here keeps the left-hand side from evaluating prematurely.

Comment: interesting use of `Unevaluated`. I thought you would have to do a `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` to get that to work. ...but of course that doesn't :)  ...sometimes you just need to see it running to know what to do

Comment: @Mike admittedly `Unevaluated` is rather unpredictable.  See Leonid's comments to [this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5723277/618728)

Comment: I must admit I would have expected the expression to remain unevaluated. I don;t work with held and unevaluated expressions that much and because of that generally don;t have an intuitive feel for it. `With` with `HoldForm` is about as sophisticated as I get :)

Comment: @Mike notice that `Unevaluated` only extends to the LHS of `/.` and in fact that part *doesn't* evaluate; ReplaceAll sees the unevaluated form and does the replacement, but Unevaluated does not persist outside of the surrounding function (in this case ReplaceAll) and therefore evaluation continues.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this produces an error is because `x` has no value and `Length[x]` returns zero. What you need to do is define x:

```
x=Flatten[Table[a 2 + b, {a, 6}, {b, 6}]];
Count[x, 8]/Length[x]
```

Comment: And that's another way to do it.

Comment: ...and also use With: `With[{x=...},Count[x, 8]/Length[x]]`